# InnoDB adaptive hash index behavior

Tags: mysql, innodb

The MySQL 5.7 documentation contains the following statement about the internals of InnoDB's adaptive hash index (AHI):

> InnoDB has a mechanism that monitors index searches. If InnoDB notices that queries could benefit from building a hash index, it does so automatically.

This is clearly quite vague and does not help me understand how InnoDB monitors searches, or what kinds of information it collects, or for what kinds of queries. **If anybody could describe the "adaptivity" of the AHI in more detail, I would really appreciate it.**

Comment: File a bug report requesting such:  http://bugs.mysql.com .  They could write such.

Comment: Good idea. I'll leave question up and post their answer (when/if) I get one.

Comment: Meanwhile, post the link to the bug.